# Synchronous request in node.js with common-node

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, httpclient, synchronous

What's wrong in this simple example?

I have compared this code with the examples in other synchronous/request examples, but I can't see it.

```
HttpClient = require('common-node').httpclient.HttpClient
Fiber = require('fibers')

google = ->
  Fiber(() ->
    console.log(new HttpClient({
      url: 'http://google.com'
    }).finish().body.read(null).decodeToString())
  ).run()

google()
```

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: Please add the error to this question, otherwise we are stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I was confused for a while why when I logged the response it would be truncated.  Finally I read that the response is iterable, and looping through it seems to be the only way to ensure you have the entire response.

```
var jsonResponse = function(json_api_url) {
    var HttpClient = require('httpclient').HttpClient;
    var response =  new HttpClient({url: json_api_url}).finish();
    var bodyString = '';
    response.body.forEach(function(stream) {
        bodyString += stream.decodeToString();
    });
    return JSON.parse(bodyString);
}
```